# maildir access problems for uid 5000:5000

Tags: permissions

I try to make my mailserver work with virtual users on /home/vmail.

but every time I see this message appear in the log

```
warning: maildir access problems for UID/GID 5000:5000: create maildir /home/vmail/domain1.com
```

but that one already exist with these permissions :

```
drwxr_x_ _ _ 3 vmail vmail 4096 april 24 09:05 domain1.com
```

How to solve this one.

Comment: Which user/group have ID 5000? Is this vmail?

Comment: yep vmail has ID and GUID 5000